# Prob. 50, Sec. 1.5, in Rosen's DISCRETE MATHEMATICS, 8th ed: Converting quantified statements into Prenex Normal Form

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

How to convert these quantified statements into Prenex Normal Form (PNF)?

(a) $\exists x P(x) \, \lor \, \exists x Q(x) \, \lor \, A$, where $A$ is a proposition not involving any quantifiers.

My Attempt:

> We find that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \qquad \exists x P(x) \, \lor \, \exists x Q(x) \, \lor \, A \\ 
> &\equiv \exists x \big( P(x) \lor Q(x) \big) \lor A \\ 
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{[ using Exercise 47, Sec. 1.4 ]} \\
> &\equiv \exists x \big( P(x) \lor Q(x) \lor A \big). \\ 
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{[ using Exercise 48 (b), Sec. 1.4 ]} 
> \end{align}
> $$

Am I right?

(b) $\lnot \big(\forall x P(x) \, \lor \, \forall x Q(x) \big)$.

My Attempt:

> We find that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \qquad \lnot \big(\forall x P(x) \, \lor \, \forall x Q(x) \big) \\ 
> &\equiv \big( \lnot \forall x P(x) \big) \land  \big( \lnot \forall x P(x) \big) \\ 
> & \qquad \mbox{[ using 2nd DeMorgan's law in } \\ 
> &\qquad \qquad \mbox{ Table 6, Sec. 1.3 ]} \\
> &\equiv \big( \exists x \lnot P(x) \big) \land \big( \exists x \lnot Q(x) \big) \\ 
> & \qquad \mbox{[ using 2nd DeMorgan's law for quantifiers in } \\
> &\qquad \qquad \mbox{ Table 2, Sec. 1.4 ]} \\
> &\equiv \exists x \exists y \big( \lnot P(x) \, \land \, \lnot Q(x) \big) \\
> &\qquad \mbox{[ using a result analogous to that } \\ 
> &\qquad \qquad \mbox{ in Exercise 48, Sec. 1.5 ]}.  
> \end{align}
> $$

Am I right?

(c) $\exists x P(x) \, \rightarrow \, \exists x Q(x)$.

My Attempt:

> We note that
> $$
> \begin{align}
> & \qquad \exists x P(x) \, \rightarrow \, \exists x Q(x) \\
> & \equiv \lnot \big( \exists x P(x) \big) \, \lor \, \big( \exists x Q(x) \big) \\
> & \qquad \mbox{[ using the conditional-disjunction equivalence ]} \\
> &\equiv \big( \forall x \lnot P(x) \big) \,  \lor \, \big( \exists x Q(x) \big) \\
> &\equiv \forall x \exists y \big( \lnot P(x) \, \lor \, Q(y) \big) \\
> &\qquad \mbox{[ using the result of Exercise 49 (b), Sec. 1.5 ]}. 
> \end{align}
> $$

Am I right?

Are my solutions to all of these three parts correct and clear enough? Or, are there any issues?